# How to Share a Google Sheet with a Group and not allow collaboration

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to share a Google Sheet with a group of people, but I do not want them to be able to make changes or 'collaborate' on the original source file.

Is there a way to create a download link for a group and prevent changes from being made to the Original file?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: either you are asking for something super basic like using "read" permission instead of "write/comment", or the question doesnt make sense.

Comment: This question is not about programming as defined in the help center, perhaps it belongs on webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

From within the sheet you can click on SHARE, then invite people to the sheet, under the "Who Can Access" part of that page, you can see "can edit", "can comment" and "can view" settings.

You will want to choose the "can view" setting.

Alternatively you could download the file and make it read-only and host it somewhere for download normally.